# SQLite: group_concat() multiple columns

Tags: sqlite

I has a problem:

In my SQLite (sqlite3 on android) database I have a table like so

```
company |  name    | job
--------------------------
      1 |  'Peter' | 'Manager'
      1 |  'Jim'   | (null)
      2 |  'John'  | 'CEO'
      2 |  'Alex'  | 'Developer'
      3 |  'Lisa'  | (null)
```

and I'd like to get to

```
company | formated
--------------------------------------
      1 | 'Peter (Manager), Jim'
      2 | 'John (CEO), Alex (Developer)'
      3 | 'Lisa'
```

What I got so far is

```
SELECT group_concat(concat) FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN job IS NULL THEN name
            ELSE name || ' (' || job || ')'
        END AS concat
    FROM jobs
)
```

which gives me all in one string

```
'Peter (Manager), Jim, John (CEO), Alex (Developer), Lisa'
```

Although that is quite good already, it's still not what I want. And at that point I fail to understand how I have to combine things to get what I want.

On a sidenote: Is there any good tutorial on complexer queries? So far I've only found some snippets but nothing that really explains how such a thing can be built

Comment: Zapl i have been searching for a whole day how to merge multiple rows into one row for a whole day thanks to your question + example that showed me the solution :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You were close!

```
SELECT 
    company,
    group_concat(concat) AS formated
FROM (
    SELECT
        company,
        CASE 
            WHEN job IS NULL THEN name
            ELSE name || ' (' || job || ')'
        END AS concat
    FROM jobs
)
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: Argh, only 2 lines more. Thx a lot

Comment: Hi how to put a filter (where) on group_concat in sqlite?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar jst before the GROUP BY clause