# Storing/Quering multiple value in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to store a blooming season in month for each tree in SQLite3. Currently I had the field "month" then I store the month name in the field. For example

```
Tree Name     Month

Tree1         Jan,Feb,Mar
Tree2         Nov,Dec,Jan
Tree3         Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
Tree4         Mar,Apr,Nov,Dec
Tree5         Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to store it, Any recommendation is appreciate.

Secondly, I need to perform a query where I enter in the month and it should return me the tree name that match the search criteria. For example

If I search for

```
 "Jan"
```

the result should be Tree1,Tree2,Tree3,Tree5

```
 "Jan,Feb,Mar"
```

the result should be Tree1,Tree3,Tree5

```
 "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr"
```

the result should be Tree5

```
 "Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec"
```

the result should be none

Which SQL query do I have to use in order to obtain the above result?

Thanks

Comment: SQL language is designed to better work with normalized databases so I recommend @Podiluska suggestion. For what you want Group_Concat could help you, check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797353/sqlite-group-concat-multiple-columns), it can be helpful, it is the opposite of what you need but it will help to get the right path. But SQL in general it is not well suited for this kind of string manipulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in following way:

```
SELECT Group_concat(name) AS [tree name] 
FROM tree 
WHERE month LIKE '%Jan,Feb,Mar%'
```

Check out **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/88152/8)**

Answer (score 3):

No. This is not the best way to store it.

You should normalise your data and store one month/tree per row

```
Tree1         Jan
Tree1         Feb
Tree1         Mar 
Tree2         Nov
Tree2         Dec
Tree2         Jan
....
```

(or perhaps store the months as numbers 1-12)

then you can

```
select treename from TreeBlooming where month = 'jan'
```

and

```
select treename from TreeBlooming
where month in ('jan','feb')
group by treename
having count(distinct month)=2
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can't really change the way the database is, as I imported it from MSAcces

Comment: Then "I'm not sure if this is the best way to store it, Any recommendation is appreciate." is a rather curious element of your question?